Random initial Orientation Madgwick filter
(ROS2 Humble) I am using the Madgwick filter to get an estimate of the imu orientation from linear accelerations and angular velocities and then I fuse the orientation (yaw) with the robot wheel odometry (vx,vy,vyaw). it is working fine however sometimes/most of the time when I start my robot I get a random initial orientation but the expected orientation would be to have the robot frame/imu frame aligned with the odom frame.
Robot_localization package is responsible for publishing tf.
The madgwick filter has the following settings :
madgwick_filter_use_mag: False
madgwick_filter_gain: 0.01
madgwick_filter_output_frame_id: imu_link
madgwick_filter_fixed_frame: base_link
madgwick_filter_world_frame: enu
madgwick_filter_publish_tf: False

How can I fix this issue?
[EDIT]: The code I am using is from this repository: https://github.com/CCNYRoboticsLab/imu_tools
Thanks.

Welcome to Robotics, Zortrax. Can you please edit your question to include a link to the source code you're using?

Thank you Chuck, I added the link as requested.

It looks like there's a method that will let you set the orientation, so I would invoke that wherever you're doing your initialization.
void setOrientation(double q0, double q1, double q2, double q3)

This assumes that you've got some knowledge of how the odom frame is aligned though, and I'm not sure how you've got that information before your IMU solution has converged.

Actually I am launching the madgwick filter node through a launch file. This is the node I am launching ROS Node

@Zortrax how are you publishing your frames? How do you know the pose for the odom frame before your IMU solution converges?

it is the robot_localization package that is publishing the odom base-link tf. I might have formulated this the wrong way but the problem is not from the fusion of the sensors but only from the filter output.
